# Cannot connect to the 5432 port postgres ubuntu

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, ubuntu-18.04, postgresql-12

Well I am trying for hours to install and configure postgres in ubuntu but getting below error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I have tried almost every solution I found but still no success.

Below are the commands I have used to install postgres:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib

sudo -i -u postgres

psql (After this I got an error)
```

The error arises during the installation of postgres.Kindly give suggestions or resources through I which I can fix this!

Comment: Did you create and start a PostgreSQL database cluster?

Comment: I used "pg_ctlcluster 12 main start"  then it gave me "Job for postgresql@12-main.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration."

Comment: @NabeelAyub try to follow this [link](https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/how-install-postgres-ubuntu)